# Inseting autocomplete value in input field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete for searching agent name and then with addAgent button, I am trying to  add a new input filed under auto complete with prepopulating the selected agent from auto complete. If I search for a name and then click add button, alert is showing ‘FirstName,LastName’ but in input filed it is showing “FirstName,” only. Any idea what is wrong?

```
    $('[name=addAgent]').click(function(){
    var agent = $('[name=insuredFirsName]').val();
    alert(agent);
        $('#1').after('<div id="1"><label >Agent Name 1</label><input name="agentName1" readOnly="Yes" size="25" value='+agent+'></div>');

    });
```

Comment: May we see the relevant markup?

Comment: Also, it looks like you're targeting an element with id 1 and inserting a div after it that will also have an id with 1.  This is invalid HTML.

Comment: It was my typo. I have removed id="1" from div tag. Still not working.